# NetBeans and JBoss

Tags: jboss5.x, netbeans-8

I am reading this tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ejb/index.htm. I have installed NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 and JBoss 5 server. And I have a problem with this part of the tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ejb/ejb_create_application.htm with jndi.properties file. I don't understand where should i put it? I have put it here C:\Users\Mimo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EjbTester\jndi.properties in my EjbTester project and I get the following exceptions.

run:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Mimo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EjbTester\jndi.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at com.tutorialspoint.test.EJBTester.(EJBTester.java:25)
    at com.tutorialspoint.test.EJBTester.main(EJBTester.java:39)
Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:350)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at com.tutorialspoint.test.EJBTester.testStatelessEjb(EJBTester.java:53)
    at com.tutorialspoint.test.EJBTester.main(EJBTester.java:41)

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Right click on project name in Project explorer window and select empty file name is jndi.properties and add info it... its work